# DÚVIDA: Divisão de layout

Tags: php, html, css, layout

Sou novo na area de desenvolvimento e estou desenvolvendo um projeto para aprendizagem.
Eis que me surge uma duvida quanto a divisão do layout.
Qual a melhor prática?
Ter separado as partes header sidebar footer content em arquivos diferentes e fazer include/require
 Ou na index deixar feito essas partes (header, sidebar, footer) e dar include/require no conteudo?
Tem diferenças no desempenho?
Em que momento devo começar a me preocupar com desempenho?

Agradeço a todos por compartilhar o conhecimento! :]

Comment: Não existe "certo" nesse caso, tudo depende de como é o conteúdo que você está programando. Você não deve se preocupar com desempenho nesse nível. Preocupe-se com o quanto suas opções facilitam a organização do seu fonte. Ter que fazer 1 include ou 10 não na mesma página não irá fazer diferença significativa para o usuário do site.

Comment: Tudo que for repetir em várias páginas pode virar include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como eu faria, separaria o `header`, `sidebar`, `footer`, e em um aquivo separado meu conteúdo, assim economizaria código, em relação a desempenho acredito não haver muita diferença, a questão maior seria organização mesmo.

- Pages

  - index
  - contato
- Includes

  - footer
  - header
  - sidebar